# css animation doesn't work with new dom-element

Tags: javascript, dom, css-animations

My css animation doesn't work?
http://jsbin.com/torococepu/1/edit?js,output

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.add-elem'),
body = document.querySelector('body');
var addNewElem = function(e) {
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'new-elem';
body.appendChild( div );
};
elem.addEventListener('click', addNewElem, false);
body.addEventListener( 'DOMNodeInserted',
function(e) { e.target.classList.add('set-height'); }, false);
```

Comment: Something on that linked page is animated. What did you expect?

Comment: added element should open smoothly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

You can trigger a custom animation. `forwards` is the `animation-fill-mode`, which defines how it has to look once the animation is finished.

```
animation: heightAnimate 1s forwards;
```

Here is the animation.

```
@keyframes heightAnimate {
    from {height: 0px;}
    to {height: 50px;}
}
```

test it here: http://jsbin.com/tobulavobi/1/edit

### Old

You could add a setTimeout when you add the class which sets the new height.

http://jsbin.com/rawepoguma/1/edit

```
body.addEventListener( 'DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    setTimeout( function () {
        e.target.classList.add('set-height');
    }, 0 );
}, false);
```

Comment: btw: don't forget the vendor prefixes

Comment: I tested it in the newest Chrome, Firefox and IE and it is wroking on all. Are your browsers up to date? Which Browsers do you need to support?

Comment: this is the "great foursome": chrome, firefox, ie and opera. for sure, it should works at least in latest browsers. there is no animation in latest firefox 36.0.1, increasing the height of block occurs instantly. also, in ie it works half by half

Comment: Works even if I add new element inside React component. Firefox 45.7, Linux. Thanks!